# Does LINQ load all items from SQL Server into memory or chunks only?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, sqldatareader

I am wondering hoq the LINQ and SqlDataProvider manages to itearate through a  WHOLE table.

**For the example below,**

- Are the whole foo items LOADED into the MEMORY at ONCE and CLR
  iterates through the foo items in the memory?
- Or the foo items are loaded from SQL Server in chunks?
- Or they are LOADED from the SQL SERVER into the MEMORT only ONE foo
  at a time?
- Or ?

```
using (var context = new FooEntities())
{
    var allItems = from foo in context.Foos
                   select foo;      

    // Are all foos LOADED into the MEMORY at once?
    // Or they come from SQL SERVER in chunks?
    foreach (f in foos)
        Console.WriteLine(f.ID);
}
```

Comment: You could easily use the SQL Profiler to answer this question yourself.

Comment: Have you tried running SQL profiler to see what LINQ is executing aginst your DB?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the ORM tool. It is unclear, but it *looks* like `FooEntities` is Entity Framework?

Firstly, note that most "full" ORMs will (by default) attach all objects it loads into an identity-manager/change-manager, which means that once objects have been seen, they'll stick around for the life of the ORM instance (although there are sometimes ways of disabling this).

Secondly, note that often the result of something like `.Foos` will be an "entity set" or similar, a fully-loaded set of data; but again, it is not *necessarily*.

Basically, it depends on a lot of details that aren't in the question. However, there often are APIs to load the data non-buffered (spooling) and without attaching to the change-manager/identity-manager. For example, LINQ-to-SQL has `ObjectTrackingEnabled` and a few other toggles.

If you are simply after a tool that will lazily spool over data, materializing rows into objects, then [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper) may be useful:

```
foreach(EntityType row in connection.Query<EntityType>(
   "select * from TableName", buffered: false))
{
    // fully streaming, no identity manager
    Console.WriteLine(row.Id);
    // ...etc
}
```

Comment: @pencilCake in the case of EF, I would *expect* (untested) that yes: if you try and enumerate an unfiltered query, it will first load the entire table into memory.

Comment: Then if I ignore to use Dapper and stick to LINQ, I do not have any simple way to make this enumeration work like SqlDataReader?

Comment: With EF? not that I *know of*. However, there may be some other more knowledgeable EF views here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as soon as start accessing it. these are loaded into the memory.

Only `virtual` properties of the objects will not be loaded.

if you want not load all the object at once you can use `Take` and `Skip` for pagination.

```
// Take only 100 objects.
var someitems = allItems.Skip(100).Take(100);
```

To have a better understanding have a look at the article.

> [Linq to SQL Deferred Loading - Lazy Load](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/06/linq-to-sql-deferred-loading-lazy-load.aspx)

Comment: So it means I am oper for an OutOfMemoryException :(
Is there a flag to set or some trick to make it load only chunks when I iterate through?

Comment: @pencilCake take a look at skip and take http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example you will mostly likely be pulling the whole table into memory. The call to the DB will be made at the start of the `foreach` and will look like a `SELECT * FROM FOO`. Try stepping over and watching a profiler as others have suggested.

SQL Server profiler is pretty good for this stuff, as is EFProfiler.  See here: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof/learn on the EFProfiler website for some 'anti-patterns' of using Linq. These apply pretty much to any sort of data access really though. Check out also Joe Albahari's LINQ quiz: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqquiz.aspx too for some interesting stuff to watch out for with LINQ.